# Add comma sepated values inside a column

Tags: python, awk

Hi I have a file format (TSV) as like this

```
Name  type    Age     Weight       Height 
Xxx   M    12,34,23  50,30,60,70   4,5,6,5.5 
Yxx   F    21,14,32  40,50,20,40   3,4,5,5.5
```

I would like to add all the values in Age, Weight and Height and add a column after this, then so some percentage also, like Total_Height/Total_Weight (awk '$0=$0"\t"(NR==1?"Percentage":$8/$7)'). I have large data set and it is not possible to do with excel.

Like this

```
Name  type    Age     Weight       Height     Total_Age Total_Weight Total_Height Percentage
Xxx   M    12,34,23  50,30,60,70   4,5,6,5.5   69        210         20.5          0.097            
Yxx   F    21,14,32  40,50,20,40   3,4,5,5.5   67        150         17.5          0.11
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following code.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print $0,"Total_Age Total_Weight Total_Height Percentage"
  next
}
FNR>1{
  totAge=totWeight=totHeight=0
  split($3,tmp,",")
  for(i in tmp){
    totAge+=tmp[i]
  }
  split($4,tmp,",")
  for(i in tmp){
    totWeight+=tmp[i]
  }
  split($5,tmp,",")
  for(i in tmp){
    totHeight+=tmp[i]
  }
  $(NF+1)=totAge
  $(NF+1)=totWeight
  $(NF+1)=totHeight
  $(NF+1)=$(NF-1)==0?"N/A":$NF/$(NF-1)
}
1' Input_file | column -t
```

***OR*** adding a bit short version of above `awk` code:

```
awk '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
FNR==1{
  print $0,"Total_Age Total_Weight Total_Height Percentage"
  next
}
FNR>1{
  totAge=totWeight=totHeight=0
  split($3,tmp,",")
  for(i in tmp){
    totAge+=tmp[i]
  }
  split($4,tmp,",")
  for(i in tmp){
    totWeight+=tmp[i]
  }
  split($5,tmp,",")
  for(i in tmp){
    totHeight+=tmp[i]
  }
  $(NF+1)=totAge OFS totWeight OFS totHeight
  $0=$0
  $(NF+1)=( $(NF-1)==0 ? "N/A" : $NF/$(NF-1) )
}
1' Input_file | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, take sum of 3rd, 4th and 5th columns and assign them to last column of line. Accordingly add column value which has divide value of last and 2nd last columns as per OP's request. Using `column -t` to make it look better on output.

Comment: In some case if all the values are zero, it will show the error like fatal division by zero attempted. How to over come this ? is it possible to put NA ?

Comment: @ZenMac, I have actually added `$(NF+1)=($NF/$(NF-1)+0)` to deal with it. It will show `0` in that case, could you please check it once.

Comment: (I used some of your awk skills in your code, I  hope you don't mind, I was trying to write a function for it)

Answer (score 5):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and without creating new fields in each record (which is inefficient as it causes awk to re-build the record every time you change a field) and without updating the input record (which is inefficient as it causes awk to re-split the record into fields every time you change the record) and designed to work for any number of value input columns in any order:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ printf "%s%s", $0, OFS }
NR==1 {
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "Total_%s%s", $i, OFS
        tags[i] = $i
    }
    print "Percentage"
    next
}
{
    delete tot
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = tags[i]
        n = split($i,vals,",")
        for (j in vals) {
            tot[tag] += vals[j]
        }
        printf "%s%s", tot[tag], OFS
    }
    printf "%0.3f%s", (tot["Weight"] ? tot["Height"] / tot["Weight"] : 0), ORS
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Name    type    Age     Weight  Height  Total_Age       Total_Weight    Total_Height    Percentage
Xxx     M       12,34,23        50,30,60,70     4,5,6,5.5       69      210     20.5    0.098
Yxx     F       21,14,32        40,50,20,40     3,4,5,5.5       67      150     17.5    0.117
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
Name  type  Age       Weight       Height     Total_Age  Total_Weight  Total_Height  Percentage
Xxx   M     12,34,23  50,30,60,70  4,5,6,5.5  69         210           20.5          0.098
Yxx   F     21,14,32  40,50,20,40  3,4,5,5.5  67         150           17.5          0.117
```

To show the functional advantages of the above approach, imagine you need to add more values like `ShoeSize` and/or rearrange the order of the columns, e.g.:

```
$ column -t file
Name  type  ShoeSize  Height     Age       Weight
Xxx   M     12,8,10   4,5,6,5.5  12,34,23  50,30,60,70
Yxx   F     9,7,8     3,4,5,5.5  21,14,32  40,50,20,40
```

Now run the above script and notice you get `Total_` columns added for every original column and you still get the same `Percentage` column of Height/Weight added to the end:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
Name  type  ShoeSize  Height     Age       Weight       Total_ShoeSize  Total_Height  Total_Age  Total_Weight  Percentage
Xxx   M     12,8,10   4,5,6,5.5  12,34,23  50,30,60,70  30              20.5          69         210           0.098
Yxx   F     9,7,8     3,4,5,5.5  21,14,32  40,50,20,40  24              17.5          67         150           0.117
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do the same operations multiple times, you might also use a function to sum the array values (given that the values are numbers separated by comma's).

Reusing some parts of the answer from @[RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13) and a massive thank you to @[Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) taking the time to provide great feedback improving the code:

```
awk '
function arraySum(field,      sum,arr,i) {
  split(field,arr,",")
  for (i in arr) sum += arr[i]
  return sum
}
FNR==1{
  print $0, "Total_Age", "Total_Weight", "Total_Height", "Percentage"
  next
}
NR > 1 {
  sumWeight = arraySum($4)
  sumHeight = arraySum($5)
  print $0, arraySum($3), sumWeight, sumHeight, (sumWeight ? sumHeight/sumWeight : 0)
}' file | column -t
```

Output

```
Name  type  Age       Weight       Height     Total_Age  Total_Weight  Total_Height  Percentage
Xxx   M     12,34,23  50,30,60,70  4,5,6,5.5  69         210           20.5          0.097619
Yxx   F     21,14,32  40,50,20,40  3,4,5,5.5  67         150           17.5          0.116667
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use GNU `AWK`'s function [`split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for this task as follows. Consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
Name  type    Age     Weight       Height 
Xxx   M    12,34,23  50,30,60,70   4,5,6,5.5 
Yxx   F    21,14,32  40,50,20,40   3,4,5,5.5
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}NR==1{print "Age","Total"}NR>1{totalage=0;split($3,ages,",");for(a in ages){totalage+=ages[a]};print $3,totalage}' file.txt
```

output

```
Age Total
12,34,23    69
21,14,32    67
```

Explanation: Firstly I informed GNU `AWK` to use tab as output field seperator (`OFS`), then for first line I print headers, for every next line I: set `totalage` value to `0`, split content of 3rd column into array `ages` at `,`, traverse said array getting sum of its values and then `print` content of 3rd column and sum. Note that

> Before splitting the string, `split()` deletes any previously existing
> elements in the arrays *array* and *seps*.

So it do not require resetting unlike `totalage` variable.

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)

Comment: Nothing in your answer requires GNU awk, it'll behave the same way in any awk. Btw your gawk version is very out of date, you should get 5.1.0 at least.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby which is a little easier for multiple data fields such as this:

```
ruby -F"\t" -lane '
if ($.==1) 
    puts "Name\ttype\tAge\tWeight\tHeight\tTotal_Age\tTotal_Weight\tTotal_Height\tPercentage"
    next 
end
fields=$F.clone
$F.each{|f| fields.append(f.split(/,/).map(&:to_f).sum) if f[/^[\d,.]+$/] && f[/,/]}
fields.append((fields[-1]/fields[-2]).round(3))
puts fields.join("\t")' file | column -t
```

Prints:

```
Name  type  Age       Weight       Height     Total_Age  Total_Weight  Total_Height  Percentage
Xxx   M     12,34,23  50,30,60,70  4,5,6,5.5  69.0       210.0         20.5          0.098
Yxx   F     21,14,32  40,50,20,40  3,4,5,5.5  67.0       150.0         17.5          0.117
```

The advantage here is that sums of columns of `n.nn,n.nn,...` are flexibly added to the end of the row in the order they are found.